# PHP Loop to search for string, execute if no match

Tags: php

I am trying to search for multiple strings within a larger string and if none of them are a match, manipulate the original string. Here is the code:

```
$searchthis = 'this is a string'
$arr = array('foo', 'bar');
foreach ($arr as &$value) {
  if (strpos($searchthis, $value) !== false) {
    break;
  }
  else{
    $searchthis = $searchthis . ' addthis';
  }
}
```

The problem is after searching the first string variable and not matching, the original searched string is manipulated before running the next test.

Any thoughts? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to be checking to see if there was not a match **outside of your loop**.  You can accomplish this by setting a variable (`$found`) to `true` when there was at least one string found:

```
$found = false;
foreach ($arr as &$value) {
  if (strpos($searchthis, $value) !== false) {
    $found = true;
  }
}
if (!$found) {
  $searchthis = $searchthis . ' addthis'; 
}
```

Comment: Thanks a ton @Tim Cooper. This did the trick. I tried outside the loop but it was setting $found variable to confirm that I didn't get. Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

Did you mean

```
$searchthis = 'this is a string'
$arr = array('foo', 'bar');
$notfound = true;
foreach ($arr as &$value) {
  if (strpos($searchthis, $value) !== false) {
    $notfound = false;
    break;
  }
}
if ($notfound){
    $searchthis = $searchthis . ' addthis';
}
```

Comment: I don't see the point of adding "break" at least not in this particular piece of code

Comment: break is so if you find your value in the first slot of the array you don't search the rest.

Answer (score 0):

Or like this:

```
$searchthis = 'this is a string';
$arr = array('foo', 'bar');
foreach ($arr as &$value) {
    if (strpos($searchthis, $value) !== false) {
        break;
    }
    else{
        if(!isset($result)) {
            $result = $searchthis . ' addthis';
        }
        else {
            continue;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: @Ruben you probably misunderstood the question else this is a mistake.
This would add/manipulate the string at the very first loop. hence if my $arr even if has the search element (say as a second element in array) result would already have the manipulated the result.